# Problem with an unknown decision

Tags: real-analysis

The following inequality is obviously true for $\frac{a}{b}$ greater than 1 ,but it is hard to show for which value of the ratio $\frac{a}{b}$ less than 1 ,
$$\frac{\ln x\ln ab x}{\ln^{2} a x}\leq\frac{a(x-1)(ab x -1)}{b(a x -1)^{2}}$$
Is still true? $x$ , $a$ and $b$ are real numbers greater than 1,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint try $ln (x)(ln (a)+ln (b)+ln (x) )/(ln (a) + ln (x))^2 \leq a^2x^2/(ax-1)^2$ which is can be shown equal to the original for positive $x,a,b $